# Handling two events sequentially in Axon

Tags: rabbitmq, axon

Can  I put a sequence between (or execute with certain time gap) two events to be handled sequentially
in axon. Both the events are created at same time. Below are the sample events.

As my second event depends on the execution results of first one. I am using RabbitMq to publish for messaging.

```
@EventHandler
public void handleEvent1(Event1 event) {
    LOG.debug("An event of type {}, occured.", event.getClass().getName());
 }

@EventHandler
public void handleEvent2(Event2 event) {
    LOG.debug("An event of type {}, occured.", event.getClass().getName());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind elaborating on the use case where you need this for?
I have an answer ready for your question, but maybe I can suggest a different course of action based on the scenario you need this in.

Events will be handled in the order they've been given to the message source you use.

From an `EventStore`, that would mean you will receive the events in the *global index* order of each of the events. The `globalIndex` is a field on each `EventMessage` used to denote it's order in the entire event store.

When using AMQP/RabbitMQ as the message source a similar ordering holds. Which ever event is earlier on the queue will be handled firstly on the consuming side.

If you thus want `Event1` to be handled prior to `Event2`, then it'll need to be published prior to the other. Control over the publication order is thus key if you require a guaranteed order. Axon doesn't provide handles to adjust the handling order of events, as it's far more ideal if your system doesn't rely on the event order directly. The handling component should stand on it's own, not making assumptions on the matter.

Hope this helps you out Amit!